# Django Allauth email verification automatically declined

Tags: django, django-allauth

I have been attempting to implement django-allauth into my project. I am using EMAIL_BACKEND to send new registerees an email that they need to confirm before they can use the application. However, every user's verification e-mail returns a view with the text:

"Confirm E-mail Address

Unable to confirm because it is already confirmed by a different account."

This is unexpected, as the documentation and other guides show they do not run into this issue.

My settings follow the allauth documentation (adding template context processor, site ID, backends, apps, and correct URLs). The optional settings are as follows:

```
    EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
    ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'username_email'
    LOGIN_URL = 'login/'
    LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'portfolio/'
    
    ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED ='True'
    ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION ='mandatory'
    ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_ANONYMOUS_REDIRECT_URL = 'login/'
    ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_ON_GET = True
    ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_EMAIL_ENTER_TWICE = True
```

**What I tried**
I checked whether, unknowingly, users are in my database that conflict with new users. I deleted all users but the superuser, and reinstalled allauth several times. I also tried to manually create an e-mail verification and verify a new user through the django shell and that worked fine.

I also created custom views to try to debug the issue at hand, for example:

```
     class CustomConfirmEmailView(ConfirmEmailView):
        def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
            print("POST method called")
            self.object = confirmation = self.get_object()
            result = confirmation.confirm(self.request)
            print('Confirmation result: ', result)
            return super().post(*args, **kwargs)


        def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
            print('ConfirmEmailView get method called')
            response = super().get(*args, **kwargs)
            confirmation = self.get_object()
            email_address = confirmation.email_address
            print('Is email verified after confirmation: ', email_address.verified)
            print("Confirmation key:", self.kwargs['key'])  # print the confirmation key
            return response


        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            ctx = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
            # Print the email_address object
            print('Email address: ', self.object.email_address)
            print('Is email verified: ', self.object.email_address.verified)
    
            return ctx

        def get_object(self, queryset=None):
            key = self.kwargs["key"]
            emailconfirmation = EmailConfirmationHMAC.from_key(key)
            print(f"Key: {key}, Email confirmation: {emailconfirmation}")
            if not emailconfirmation:
                if queryset is None:
                    queryset = self.get_queryset()
                try:
                    emailconfirmation = queryset.get(key=key.lower())
                except EmailConfirmation.DoesNotExist:
                    raise Http404()
            return emailconfirmation
```

Whilst testing I made sure to override the accounts view with these custom views. (Please note that this issue is still present with both custom and source views).

Whilst debugging, I retraced the issue to the can_confirm boolean in the source HTML template.

```
    {% if confirmation %}
    
    {% user_display confirmation.email_address.user as user_display %}
    
    {% if can_confirm %}
```

The form is never entered, where the can_confirm is thus always false. I think it is due to allauth's get_context_data always having "can_confirm" on false

```
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ctx = kwargs
        site = get_current_site(self.request)
        ctx.update(
            {
            "site": site,
            "confirmation": self.object,
            "can_confirm": self.object.email_address.can_set_verified(),
            "email": self.object.email_address.email,
            }
        )
        return ctx
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I am facing the same issue..

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution through GitHub. My Allauth version is 0.54.0, which is not the same as the code shown in the main branch on GitHub.

To solve this issue, do the following:

1. Check your Allauth version (`pip show django-allauth`)
2. Go to Allauth's GitHub, press the branch overview, and switch to the "Tags" tab. This should give you an overview of related code.
3. Switch to your version and copy the templates. The issue here was that the code for `can_confirm` was not released in the pip version, so `can_confirm` will never be `True`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Related Github solved issue as of July 2023: https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/issues/3354